# How to use an action link to get a confirmation popup before going to a controller action?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, actionlink

I have an action link that calls a controller method and passes some data to enable or disable a user in a database system.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Change Status", "ChangeStatus", "Home", new { userName = ViewBag.userName, applicationName = item.Key, currentStatus = item.Value }, new { @class = "enableDisable" })
```

This link works fine except there should be a JQuery popup message appearing to confirm the action before the controller method is called. However the action link bypasses the popup and calls the controller directly.

```
@section Scripts {

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#dialog-confirm").hide();
        $(function () {
            $(".enableDisable").click(function () {
                $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                    resizable: false,
                    height: 220,
                    width: 475,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "OK": function () {

                            $(this).dialog("close");

                            window.location.href = "~/Home/ChangeStatus/userName/applicationName/currentStatus/"
                        },
                        Cancel: function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Does anyone know what I am missing from my code to make this work correctly?

**Edit**

The JQuery is now in a js file and is being called by the following code:

```
@section Scripts {
    <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.11.1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Dialog.js"></script>
}
```

The JQuery itself looks like this now:

```
$("#dialog-confirm").hide();
$(function () {
    $(".enableDisable").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 220,
            width: 475,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function () {

                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    window.location.href = url;
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Razor view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "User Details";
}

<h2>User Details</h2>

<p><b>@ViewBag.UserName</b></p>

    <table class="table">
         <tr>
             <th>
                 Application Name
             </th>
            <th>
               Status
            </th>
             <th>

             </th>
             <th>

             </th>

        </tr>

            @if (ViewBag.ApplicationStatuses.Count > 0)
            {
                @*Iterating Amadeus model using ViewBag *@
                foreach (var item in ViewBag.ApplicationStatuses)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item.Key
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.Value
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       @Html.ActionLink("Change Status", "ChangeStatus", "User", new { userName = ViewBag.userName, applicationName = item.Key }, new { @class = "enableDisable" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("View Roles", "Roles", new { userName = ViewBag.UserName, applicationName = item.Key })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                }
            } 

</table>
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Change Status?">
    Are you sure you want to change the status of: @ViewBag.UserName?
</div>

@section Scripts {

    <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.11.1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Dialog.js"></script>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `e.preventDefault()` and make some changes as shown below :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //$("#dialog-confirm").hide();
    $(function () {
        $(".enableDisable").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 220,
                width: 475,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "OK": function () {

                        //$(this).dialog("close");

                        window.location.href = url;  //<-------
                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
          $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open"); // <------- open dialog this way.
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunatly that hasn't helped, I have updated my question to supply the code in the js file and the code that calls the js file.

Comment: @SlipperyBalmain...sorry but i m not getting you want you are trying to do now ...and see carefully in my answer you haven't used 'e' in ...function(e)...??

Comment: hmm actually that is a good point, I have that code now and the jquery does not function. I seem to be making changes strangely at the minute.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing but instead of my jQuery being in the same file as the action link it is now in a js file and there is a script reference in the file containing the action link. I have included the entire razor code now for view.

Comment: not that I can find. The problem seems to be, when I try to change the status of any application only the first application in the list is updated. The problem only now occurs when my popup is activated and the javascript is in a seperate file to the razor view. By debugging I have found that the jquery popup button is only finding the href of the first action link created, but I cant seem to figure out why when it works when in the same file. Does this explain the issue better? What steps can I take to try to fix this?

Comment: @SlipperyBalmain...sorry but i am not getting you ... 2 days back you asked the question... i solved your problem with best of my knowledge....now you are extending the question..in my opinion just post a new question with sufficient explanation..the problem is that i m not getting you what actually you want..

Comment: Hi sorry the issue I had was when I copied my code across I missed ` $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");` that has fixed the issue that cropped up again. Thank-you for your patience my team has been trying to find the problem all day.